# how often deadlock detection to be done?

Tags: operating-system

If deadlocks are less likely to occur in the system and processes are frequently requesting resources what are the main logical reasons due to which we must only run the deadlock algorithm only when they occur and not in a continuous loop testing the deadlock condition to be true?

Comment: I suspect this should be asked in our [unix](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) site

Answer (score 0):

This is highly system dependent. Quality operating systems incorporate general purpose locking mechanisms as system services that detect deadlocks. Deadlock checks are normally instigated when a process requests a lock; not through continuous loop.

Many quick and dirty system have no deadlock detection at all.

Comment: ...like Windows and Linux.

Comment: Is Running a Deadlock detection algorithm on the system after a specified period of time a good approach for the deadlock detection?

Comment: I don't think so because a deadlock is going to occur when someone locks a resource.